# How can I access the parent class instance from a class attribute, specifically a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a chat bubble button that calls a menu to copy the text or image to the pasteboard. I can access the button itself when I handle long press and double tap, however I need to be able to access the message attribute contained in the cell instance alongside the chat bubble button.

I'm aiming to use the `cell.chatBubble` reference passed from the action function to retrieve a reference to the cell in order to access `message` data.

```
func selfMessageCellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> SelfMessageCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SelfMessageCellIdentifier) as! SelfMessageCell

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

    cell.messageLabel.text = message.messageContents
    let messageWidth = cell.messageLabel.intrinsicContentSize().width
    if messageWidth < (cell.bounds.width * 0.7 - 42) {
        cell.chatWidth = messageWidth + 33
    }

    cell.chatBubble.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCopyGesture(_:))))

    cell.chatBubble.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCopyGesture(_:))))
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCopyGesture(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    cell.chatBubble.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    cell.transform = self.tableView.transform

    return cell
}


// Extension for chat bubble press handling
extension MessageSuperViewController {
func handleCopyGesture(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        openCopyMenu(recognizer)
    }
    else if !UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuVisible{
        openCopyMenu(recognizer)
    }
}

func openCopyMenu(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let recognizerView = recognizer.view, recognizerSuperView = recognizer.view?.superview {
        let menuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
        let copyItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action: #selector(copyMessageContents(_:)))
        let moreItem = UIMenuItem(title: "More..", action: #selector(moreMenuItem(_:)))
        menuController.menuItems = [copyItem,moreItem]
        menuController.setTargetRect(recognizerView.frame, inView: recognizerSuperView)
        menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        recognizerView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func copyMessageContents(sender: UIMenuItem) {

}

func moreMenuItem(sender: UIMenuItem) {

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `handleCopyGesture(_:)` method?

Comment: It doesn't do much, I just need a conditional statement for messages with text or an image

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside `SelfMessageCell` and when you have the event fired you can use a delegate like:

```
SelfMessageCellDidTapDelegate(sender: SelfMessageCell)
```

and in this class where you have `selfMessageCellForRowAtIndexPath` you implement the this delegate and `sender` will contain the data you want.

```
func selfMessageCellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> SelfMessageCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SelfMessageCellIdentifier) as! SelfMessageCell
    cell.delegate = self
    ....
}

SelfMessageCellDidTapDelegate(sender: SelfMessageCell) {
    print(sender)
}
```

Comment: How would I modify this to be used when the user presses the copy `UIMenuItem` which is a little different from just long pressing the chatBubble button

Comment: in your delegate you can pass `recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer`as second paramenter so you don't break your current code

Comment: @ggworean if your `recognizer.view` is your `chatBubble` you can have the visibility of it with `sender.chatBubble`